# negative-lookahead in gsub

Tags: r, regex

In a recent scenario I wanted to extract the very last part of a vector of url's.
Eg.

```
> urls <- c('https::abc/efg/hij/', 'https::abc/efg/hij/lmn/', 'https::abc/efg/hij/lmn/opr/')
> rs <- regexpr("([^/])*(?=/$)", urls, perl = TRUE)
> substr(urls, rs, rs + attr(rs, 'match.length'))
[1] "hij/" "lmn/" "opr/"
```

which is somewhat simple to read. But I'd like to understand how I could do something similar by inverting the lookahead expression, eg. remove the second to last '/' and anything preceding (assuming that the string always ends with '/'). I can't seem to get the exact logic straight,

```
> gsub('([^/]|[/])(?!([^/]*/)$)', '', urls, perl = TRUE)
[1] "/hij" "/lmn" "/opr"
```

Basically I'm looking for the regexp logic that would return the result in the first example, but using only a single `gsub` call.

Comment: `sub(".*/([^/]*/)$", "\\1",urls)` ([demo](https://ideone.com/rckrvG))

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Seems I got lost in the sauce. If you add this as an answer with 1 - 2 lines of text to accompany it, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: You can also use a lookahead, although less efficient `^.*[^/]+/(?=[^/]*/$)` https://regex101.com/r/kEayEq/1

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird. Indeed this was an excercise in learning about look-aheads and negative-lookaheads so this is a bit more to my liking. Although I would have liked this to be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I'll heed my word and accept your answer even if it is a duplicate. Although I will "revoke" the acceptance for anyone giving an example using negative-lookaheads, so I can see where my logic fails. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a match only, you could still use the lookahead construct:

```
^.*/(?=[^/]*/$)
```

- `^` Start of the string
- `.*/` Match until the last `/`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[^/]*/$` assert what is at the right is 0+ times any char except `/`, then match `/` at end of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/72tB3i/1) | [R example](https://ideone.com/YCNeiA)

For example

```
gsub('^.*/(?=[^/]*/$)', '', urls, perl = TRUE)
```

---

An option using a negative lookahead:

```
^.*/(?!$)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*/` Match the last `/`
- `(?!$)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rTKBUo/1/)

Comment: Just going to clear very quickly: This is about 40 % faster than substituting the match, using a simple `microbenchmark`. Thanks, if no one comes with a 'negative-lookahead' answer i'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Oliver Well, using a negative lookahead could be `^.*/(?!$)` so you backtrack until the second last `/` asserting it is not the last `/` https://regex101.com/r/rTKBUo/1

Comment: That simply just works. Removing the redundant `^` it is (very slightly) faster than look-ahead. I didn't realize you could use negative look-ahead to simply assert "not at the end of". Neat!

Answer (score 1):

The non-regex & very quick solution would be to use `basename()`:

```
basename(urls)
[1] "hij" "lmn" "opr"
```

Or, for your case:

```
paste0(basename(urls), '/')
[1] "hij/" "lmn/" "opr/"
```

Answer (score 0):

my prefered method is to replace the whole string with parts of the string, like so:

```
gsub("^.*/([^/]+/)$", "\\1", urls)
```

The `"\\1"` matches whatever was matched inside `()`.
So Basically I am replacing the whole string with the last part of the url.